# Xcode 7.3.1 issue navigator show warnings of third party libs

Tags: xcode, xcode7.3

In Xcode 7.3.1, issue navigator don't show warnings of third party libs by default.How to show the warnings like old version?

Comment: `File > Project Settings…`, change `Show issues for active scheme only` to `Show all issues`? Not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: to show all issues for the active scheme and all issues for the third party libs which are dependent by the scheme @NSGod

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5299,here is the solution for cocoapods,`add the Pods-MyApp target as part of the build items`